# Bootstrap devided screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to split my html page into two tables with button in the middle. I want to set fix width to the buttons (e.g. 40 px distance between the two tables in every screen size). The tables have to have the same width and they have to fill the screen horizontally. How can I create this layout with Bootstrap?

[image]

Comment: You may provide some code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with some custom code for example.

```
<div class="el">
  <div class="elLeft">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="elbtn">
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="#" role="button"> &lt; </a>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="#" role="button"> &gt; </a>
  </div>
  <div class="elRight">

    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


</div>
```

css

```
.el {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.elLeft,.elRight,.elbtn {
  display: table-cell;
}

.elbtn {
  padding: 0 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
}

.elbtn .btn {
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

[Demo here](http://www.bootply.com/LGh47JhKsR)

Answer (score 1):

Inside a `container` or `container-fluid`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    TABLE 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    BUTTONS
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    TABLE 2
  </div>
</div>
```

and check the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to see how to create tables and buttons as you want

Comment: I don't want to set col-xs-2 to the button column, because I want a fix width for this column. (e.g. 40 px in every screen)